# comma in raw_input function

Tags: python

What would be the output of this ? I see the output but not able to understand why that happens.

```
def multiple(x,y):  
    mul = x*y  
    return mul  

x=int(raw_input("Enter value 1 ")),  
y=int(raw_input("Enter value 2 "))  
print multiple(x,y)
```

Answer (score 4):

In your code, the `,` at the end of the first `raw_input` means `x` is actually a `tuple` containing the user input. When you call the function, what you are actually doing is multiplying the tuple by an integer, which just multiplies the tuple (`x`) `y` times.

For example:

```
>>> x = 2,
>>> x * 5
(2, 2, 2, 2, 2)
>>> x = 2
>>> x * 5
10
```

Answer (score 2):

The comma makes `x` equal to a tuple of size 1 (containing the int).

Simple test:

```
>>> a = 1,
>>> print a
(1,)
```

Answer (score 2):

A large error with this is that if x and y are not numbers (aka a string), the function would be messed up. This can be fixed by saying:
        `try:
            mul = float(x) * float(y)`
then, to catch the case when x or y are not numbers,
        `except TypeError:
            print('Please do not give a string...')`
In this case, you want to show that mul is not valid, so you say,
            `mul = None`
Now you can `return mul` in line with the try and except statements.

This ensures that the inputs are decimal point numbers, not characters.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you define a function called `multiple` and it multiplies `x` and `y` (parameters of `multiple`), then returns that value. Then it takes input for two different variables, `x` and `y` (not the same as the parameters above), multiplies (by calling `multiple`), and `print`s them out, which is what you see as output.

The comma however, simply defines `x` as a tuple.